# Extract algebraic signs from string

Tags: string, r, extract, formula

I have a string as follows

```
str <- "- var_a + var_c - var_d"
```

and I want to change the values in a vector `vec`

```
 vec <- c(var_a=0, var_b=0, var_c=0, var_d=0, var_e=0)
 vec
 var_a var_b var_c var_d var_e 
    0     0     0     0     0
```

according to `str`: whenever a variable has a negative sign, set the corresponding entry in `vec` to -1, if it has a positive sign to 1. My desired output would look like this:

```
var_a var_b var_c var_d var_e 
   -1     0     1    -1     0
```

My idea was to try to loop over all names of `vec` and use a regex to extract the corresoponding sign in `str`, but I don't really know how to get the sign, with for 
instance `lapply(names(vec), grepl, str)` I can only see which of the variable are in the string.

Isn't there an easier way, for example with `formula` or `expression` ? I also looked at the package `Ryacas` but could not find what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `scan` to read and split data. The scan read data an put it in a vector.

```
vec <- c(var_a=0, var_b=0, var_c=0, var_d=0, var_e=0)
ll <- scan(text=str,what='string')
## EDIT here to treat the case the first elment is not a sign
## i.e: var_a + var_c - var_d
pos <- ll %in% c('-','+')
if(length(ll[pos]) != length(ll[!pos])) ll <- append(ll,'+',0)
vec[ll[!pos]] <- ifelse(ll[pos] == '-',-1,1)
```

Comment: This also gives correct results for both `"var_a + var_c - var_d"` and `"+ var_a + var_c - var_d"`

Comment: @user1981275 I am afraid that it was not. No it should  work for both situations after my edit.

Answer (score 4):

This works for your example:

```
splitted <- strsplit(str, " ")[[1]]
signs <- splitted[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
vars  <- splitted[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

vec[vars] <- ifelse(signs == "+", 1, -1)
```

Would the first sign on the first variable be positive, would you have a leading `+` as in `str <- "+ var_a + var_c - var_d"`? If not, you will have to handle that separately.

Comment: Both cases can occur, either nothing or a trailing "+", which makes a bit more complicated.

Comment: Not really, just add `if (length(splitted) %% 2) splitted <- c('+', splitted)`. Sorry I did not follow up right away (I wish someone did) as I was not near the computer.

Answer (score 2):

I like the `regex` approach, but you have to be careful that the regex is compatible with your variable names. This splits the string on spaces that are preceeded by a letter character (you could use `[[:alphanum:]]` to be more flexible but I'm not sure if you would have numbers in your string...

```
#  Split variables
args <- strsplit( str , "(?<=[a-z])\\s" , perl = TRUE )[[1]]

#  Extract sign and convert to integer
sign <- as.integer( paste0( strtrim(args , 1 ) , 1 ) )

# Match and change the corresponding values of vec
vec[ match( substring( args , first = 3 ) , names(vec) ) ] <- sign
#var_a var_b var_c var_d var_e 
#   -1     0     1    -1     0
```

Comment: +1 for the use of regular expression! it is always a challenging task.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of a probably slow approach along the lines of

```
# set up initial condition
var_a<-var_b<-var_c<-etc<-0
 varnames<-c('var_a','var_b','var_c', etc)

values<-rep(0,length(varnames))
# test one by one to see what you get, w/ apologies in advance for evalparse
for (j in 1: length(varnames) ) {
    assign(varnames[j],1)
    values[j]<- eval(parse(str))
    assign(varnames[j],0)
}
```

Then the values in `values` will tell you the sign of the variable in your string.
Ugly but fun to design :-)